# Zoho Creator Deluge : how to dynamically create a temporary form?

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

Zoho Creator Deluge : how to dynamically create a temporary form?

I tried a test deluge script in creator to dynamically generate a form. Here is the example code:

```
void generate_form()
{
    form zc_add_employee
    {
    displayname = "ZC Add Employee"
    }
}
```

However, it fails on save and reports "Improper Statement Error might be due to missing ';' at the end of the line or incomplete expression".

Also I searched around on the web for examples of how to do this but didn't find anything.  So there are 2 questions.

1. Is it possible to dynamically create and remove a soho-creator form within a deluge script?
2. and if so,  what is the proper syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think creating a form dynamically is supported through deluge,

its only possible manually either

- using drag & drop form builder
- or from modifying the Application IDE in the settings
  ( you can use u'r code in the application IDE, but still its manual way so better to use the drag & drop form builder )